# Wi-Fi does not working in Dell Inspiron 5502 with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, dell

I bought a Dell Inspiron 5502 i5502-M40S. It comes with Windows 10 pre-installed, after some "exercise" I managed to install Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot. To do this I changed from RAID to AHCI and disabled de secure boot.

However when I log in from Ubuntu the wifi is not enabled. Bluetooth is not working either. The curious thing is that on live usb everything works perfectly.

In Windows all is OK. Note that this notebook does not have an ethernet port.

From **lspci** I have
Network controller: Intel Corporation Device [8086:42a4]
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255

```
:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:838 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='iwlwifi'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

There are no return messages for `rfkill list all` or for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Thanks chili, question edited.

Comment: Any result for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, there's no results for this either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your readings show that the package linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) that provides the driver iwlwifi among many others, didn't get installed in your new installation. I suggest that you do, while connected to the internet by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

Upon rebooting, your wireless should now be working.

I also recommended:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic
```

...because its dependencies and their dependencies include linux-modules-extra.

Comment: Thanks chili. There's no ethernet port in this notebook. I will buy an usb-RJ45 adapter. This way I think I will be able to proceed the downloads.

Comment: Finally I have my notebook with WiFi, Bluetooth and sound. I reinstall Ubuntu but, still on live usb, before actually installing it, I used the "Programs and Updates" application and checked all the options of applications to download from the internet (proprietary drivers, restricted applications) and the additional drivers. Just in case, I also ran the sudo apt install linux-modules-extra... command. When I restarted everything worked fine and there was, in the additional drivers, an Intel Corporate hardware support for Dell Inspiron 5402/5502 (among others).

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it's working as expected. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour